# parsing text file into mySQL database

Tags: php, sql, database, parsing, logfile

I want to parse a log file into a table in my database using PHP, but I keep getting an error saying

> php parse error, unexpected mysql_select_db command

any ideas??

Here's my code;

```
<?
$handle = @fopen("NeXposeResults.txt","r");
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost")
mysql_select_db("resultsdb.mwb",$conn);

$values=;

while (!feof($handle))
{
    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
    list ($a,$b,$c)=explode("|",$buffer);
    values.=($a,$b,$c);

    INSERT INTO storage (Description, Severity, Risk Score,)
    VALUES ($a,$b,$c,)
}
?>
```

Comment: resultsdb.mwb you're sure that this is your db name?

Comment: - Dont' use mysql_, use mysqli_ or PDO http://phpmaster.com/avoid-the-original-mysql-extension-1/ 
- .mwb is a mysql workbench file and not a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon on line 3.

`$conn = mysql_connect("localhost")` should be `$conn = mysql_connect("localhost");`

Comment: No worries.  You're also missing them inside of your while loop:

    `INSERT INTO storage (Description, Severity, Risk Score,)
    VALUES ($a,$b,$c,)`

should read

    `INSERT INTO storage (Description, Severity, Risk Score,);
    VALUES ($a,$b,$c,);`